# SQL Grouping through temptable and getting new column value if one of the column value is 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 columns in table in my DB and want to achieve following in SQL

```
Create table #TempTableChild 
(
     Child_Id int, 
     UnReadCount int,
     Adult_id int
)
```

I have following values in `#TempTableChild`:

```
Child_Id | UnreadCount | AdultId |   NewColumnVal
---------+-------------+---------+----------------
28       |      1      |    4    |         0
29       |      1      |    4    |         0
28       |      0      |    5    |         0   
29       |      0      |    5    |         0   
5        |      1      |    6    |         0   
6        |      0      |    8    |         0
```

And, want to achieve below data.

```
Child_Id | UnreadCount | AdultId |   NewColumnVal
---------+-------------+---------+----------------
28       |      1      |    4    |         1
29       |      1      |    4    |         0
28       |      0      |    5    |         0   
29       |      0      |    5    |         0   
5        |      1      |    6    |         1   
6        |      0      |    8    |         0
```

I want top value of NewColumnVal = 1 when for each distinct AdultId as shown above.

When for `AdultId = 4 UnreadCount = 1 NewColumnVal =1` for first Child_Id only then all other subsequent values of NewColumnVal = 0 then again for new adult_id top value of NewColumnVal = 0 if UnreadCount = 0

Comment: Case statement will do the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window function together with Case Statement. see Below:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t (
>   Child_Id INT,
>   UnreadCount INT,
>   AdultId INT,
>   NewColumnVal INT
> );
>
> INSERT INTO t
>   (Child_Id, UnreadCount, AdultId, NewColumnVal)
> VALUES
>   ('28', '1', '4', '0'),
>   ('29', '1', '4', '0'),
>   ('28', '0', '5', '0'),
>   ('29', '0', '5', '0'),
>   ('5', '1', '6', '0'),
>   ('6', '0', '8', '0');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 6 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select 
>   Child_Id,
>   UnreadCount, 
>   AdultId, 
>   CASE WHEN UnreadCount > 0 AND rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END NewColumnVal
> from (
>   select *,
>     row_number() over (partition by AdultId order by Child_Id ) rn
>   from t
> ) tou
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Child_Id | UnreadCount | AdultId | NewColumnVal
> -------: | ----------: | ------: | -----------:
>       28 |           1 |       4 |            1
>       29 |           1 |       4 |            0
>       28 |           0 |       5 |            0
>       29 |           0 |       5 |            0
>        5 |           1 |       6 |            1
>        6 |           0 |       8 |            0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d935b10d7fcd72dfb1c155bd0e64cc4b)*

Comment: Thanks Simonare for quick and easy solution. Can you provide explanation on your query as I am just beginner of SQL.